# R6034 runtime error after renaming Visual Studio 2008 MFC project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, manifest

I was recently tasked with doing a complete rename of one of our company's products. Currently it is built using MFC in Visual Studio 2008. I attempted to do the rename from within Visual Studio by using Find/Replace as well as renaming various project properties; however, when I ran it (after successful build/link) I got the following error:

> Runtime Error!
>
> Program: d...
>
> R6034
>
> An application has made an attempt
> to load the C runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

[image]

I figured I had messed something up, so I pulled a clean copy of the project, confirmed that it built/linked/ran fine and then proceeded to rename using an external editor. After a tedious hour or so I had renamed everything. When running, I encountered the same R6034 error.

I started diving into this error and most of the time it seemed to be caused by a missing manifest file. I compared the good (original name) copy of the application's settings and everything is identical save for a few names. The manifest is being generated and is embedded. I opened the executable in VS2008 and confirmed RT_MANIFEST existed and had an ID of 1. The manifest itself is identical to the one in the working assembly. I tried using an external manifest and the same problem occurred.

It is looking like I might have to port this entire application by hand, but I still have no way of knowing if that will actually work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your manifest file? It could be that the previous version of you program used MS CRT 7.0 files, and the new one wants to use 8.0.

Comment: Boring answer but... I think you need to go a little slower on the rename. Make a few changes then build and test, repeat. You'll find which rename is causing the problem eventually. It's normally down to something like trying to load the Debug CRT and Release CRT at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I figured out the issue. See forthcoming answer.

cha - It's definitely not trying to use the wrong version of the CRT. The two manifest files are identical in version and all.

snowdude - This was my next move. There is a lot to do but it seems rational. Fortunately it is a non-issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. I wish I had some profound moment of insight, but it was a simple mistake:

One of the other tasks I had undertaken simultaneously with the rename (mistake #1) was to remove an Intel Fortran library project that was in the solution. That code will rarely (if ever change) and so we wanted to remove it to streamline the process of building on another machine without the Intel compilers installed. Part of this step was manually adding the library to the linker input list. Well, I accidentally added the release library to the debug version and therein was the cause of the problem. As soon as I corrected it and made it the debug version it linked correctly.

I don't quite understand the reason this caused a problem. I've used release libraries in debug versions (and vice versa) in the past, but for some reason throwing Intel and/or Fortran into the mix messed things up.

Thanks for everyone's time.